# Neurology: spinal tract

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

I have had a few difficulties finding answers for the questions below. I have tried answering the first two myself; but, I am not sure they are correct or not. And I am not too sure about the third one.

1. In which structure of the brain does the axon from the spinocerebellum tract synapese? Is it the cerebellum?
2. Are the cell bodies of axon in the gracile tract located at the dorsal root, tectospinal tract located in cerebral cortex?
3. Which region  of spinal cord carries feed-forward information to help accommodate for upcoming motor movement?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the spinocerebellar tract ends in the [ipsilateral cerebellum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinocerebellar_tract).
2. The gracile tract is a bundle of axon fibers in the dorsal root. The neural cell bodies are in the [dorsal root ganglions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsal_root_ganglion). The tectospinal tract is part of extrapyramidal tract that connects midbrain (mesencephalon) with the spinal cord.
3. Didin't get exactly what you meant but: the lateral corticospinal tract (part of pyramidal tracts) controls fine movement of ipsilateral limbs, while the anterior corticospinal tract (part of the pyramidal tracts) conducts voluntary motor impulses from the precentral gyrus.

Source: Wikipedia: *[Tectospinal tract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tectospinal_tract), [Spinocerebellar tract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinocerebellar_tract), [Dorsal root ganglion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsal_root_ganglion), [Pyramidal tracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_tracts), [Anterior corticospinal tract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_corticospinal_tract), [Lateral corticospinal tract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_corticospinal_tract).*